# When doing 2 pass video encoding with FFmpeg, how to find the optimal bitrate?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, bitrate

When doing 2 pass video encoding with VP8 (libvpx), is there a way to figure out the optimal bitrate, so I don't have to guess?

Something like a small compression test, or some ffmpeg command, that will help me determine the appropriate bitrate?

I tried reading the VP8 1st pass stats file in notepad, but it's all garbled.

I'm using Windows 7 with the latest FFmpeg build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a constant quality rate control (CRF) that will let the encoder choose an optimal bitrate ?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 20M -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

The CRF value can be set within [4 ; 63], 4 being the best quality. 10 is a well accepted value. The specified `-b:v 20M` becomes the maximum allowed bitrate.

Two-pass encoding should only be used when you need a fixed-size file, otherwise, CRF is the preferred method.

More information in the [VP8/FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8#VariableBitrate) article.

Comment: This CRF value seems low, but maybe the ranges are specific to an encoder?

Comment: It's CRF specific to the VP8 encoder which is different from x264's CRF.